# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/safaridriver

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

Basically, on my Mac, selenium is not working. My code is as such:

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Safari('/usr/bin/safaridriver')
```

This is practically the most basic selenium script, yet it doesn't work...
After 30 seconds of my program running, I get this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/safaridriver`. I have no idea why this is happening... my safari version is up to date, (14.0.1), yet I keep getting this error.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: What  code are you running at that point , add the code where the error is happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first positional argument passed to `webdriver.Safari` isn't the `executable_path` argument, but is the `port` argument. You would have to pass the path as a positional argument.

```py
webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
```